# Windows Phone 7: How to access built-in Calculator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, calculator, built-in

Does anyone know how to access the built-in calculator from my application on Windows Phone 7? I have googled it for about 4 hours and I couldn't find an answer.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? Open it? Redirect Execution and poll for a result?  What is your end goal?

Comment: I want to open the Calculator from device when a button from my application is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not possible with the Windows Phone 7 SDK: for launching apps/services, you need to use `Launchers` but in the [launchers list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), there isn't the calculator.

Even on Windows Phone 8 where you have access to [more launchers via URI schemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), there is no way to launch the calculator.

Comment: That seems related to opening files associated with an app, but I believe that's not precisely what he's looking for. I think he, instead, wants to launch the calculator, not open a file with the calculator. I believe what he's looking for would be the WP7 equivalent of WP8's [Package.Launch() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.package.launch.aspx).

Comment: Launchers allows to open Internet Explorer, Marketplace app, Maps app, etc. so it would have made sense to allow opening the Calculator app too. Package.Launch() on WP8 only allows to launch apps that share the  same Publisher GUID, so I don't think it could be used to launch the Calculator app.

Comment: Really? I'd have thought if you knew the GUID, you could construct an object for launching any app. I know some apps act as launchers (like those for custom tile creation). Never tried one on with the Calculator app, admittedly, though.